# GOOGLE SCRIPT Why a function is running when it's not called in the script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem that I can't seem to be able to resolve. Basically, I have a Project where I have all my scripts. For some reason, all of a sudden and with no apparent reason, when I try to execute a script, it executes all the script at once... why does it happen? Specifically, I need to execute my script "copiaInEffettivo", but when I do it triggers the other 2 as well. Before this afternoon, everything was fine.
I copy here all my scripts together, but I highlight the fact that in the editor all these functions have their own separate file:

```
function colorazioneCaselle() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var PRAG = ss.getSheetByName("PRAG");
  var colors = ss.getSheetByName("colors");
  var row = 3;
  var col = 2;
  var cella = colors.getRange(row, col);
  var valcel = cella.getValue();
  var i = 0;
  while (col != 47) {
    while (i != 24) {
      if (valcel != "") {
        var x = 0;
        var y = 29;
        while (x != 17) {
          var cella2 = colors.getRange(y, 3).getValue();
          if (valcel == cella2) {
            var colore = colors.getRange(y, 1).getBackgroundColor();
            PRAG.getRange(row + 1, col + 1).setBackgroundColor(colore);
            x = 17;
          }
          else if (valcel != cella2) {
            y++;
            x++;
          }
        }
      }
      row++;
      valcel = colors.getRange(row, col).getValue();
      i++;
      Logger.log("cella giù");
    }
    col++;
    row = 3;
    valcel = colors.getRange(row, col).getValue();
    i = 0;
    Logger.log("cambio colonna")
  }
}



function controlloCasellaEffettivo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var effettivo = ss.getSheetByName('effettivo');
  var info = ss.getSheetByName('info');
  var row = 3;
  var row2 = 3;
  var col = 7;
  var col2 = 5;
  var cellauno = effettivo.getRange(row, col);
  var luogo = info.getRange(row2, col2);
  for(var y = 0; y < 27; y++)
  {
  var i = 0;
  while(i < 155) 
      { 
      if (cellauno.isChecked() === true)
        {var contenuto = effettivo.getRange(row, 3).getValues();
        luogo.setValues(contenuto);
        row2++;
        luogo = info.getRange(row2, col2);
        }
      row++;
      cellauno = effettivo.getRange(row, col);
      i++;
      }
    col++;
    col2++;
    row2 = 3;
    row = 3;
    luogo = info.getRange(row2, col2);
    cellauno = effettivo.getRange(row, col);
  }
}
colorazioneCaselle()



function copiaInEffettivo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pianificazione = ss.getSheetByName('pianificazione');
  var effettivo = ss.getSheetByName('effettivo');
  var contenuto = pianificazione.getRange(3, 3, 154, 30);
  contenuto.copyTo(effettivo.getRange(3, 3));
  pianificazione.hideSheet()
}
```

The first script basically applies color to cells based on their content, the second one extracts and transfers some informations into a sheet and the third one simply copies data from one sheet to another and then hides the first one. "ControlloCasellaEffettivo", as you can see, calls "ColorazioneCaselle" at the end. Any guesses on why this happens?

Comment: Could you share a  [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue? It is not common that the functions are being triggered on it's own if you are not running them

Comment: Would you be able to provide a copy of your sheet with sanitized (or dummy) values as part of trying to troubleshoot as well as for us to be able to test it out first? FYI. Providing a sample sheet would expose your email address to the public, so if you're not comfortable with this, we would understand.

Comment: I suppose you've checked the executions to see how they're being run!?

Comment: This line `colorazioneCaselle()` which is in global space will cause this function to be called when ever you call any function.  In fact I suppose if you call that function from the script editor it may be called twice

Comment: Check project triggers for unwanted triggers

Comment: First of all, thank you guys for the quick responses :)
Gabriel: the example is this: I have a button to launch the "copiaInEffettivo" function in my spreadsheet, but when I click it it takes way too much time, because it's triggering the other functions too... 
Diego: unfortunatly this is something I must fix for my workplace, so I cant share any files, because it is full of reserved datas :/ Santos: how do I do that? I'm pretty new to the coding scene, I'm just getting started :p Cooper: how could I fix it? I need to run it  immediatly after I run the "controlloCasellaEffettivo" function

Comment: If you cant share any files, then at least create a sample sheet using sample values that imitates yours for us to be able to understand your data more.